# Splitting a python string at a delimiter but a specific one

Tags: python

Is there a way to split a python string without using a for loop that basically splits a string in the middle to the closest delimiter.

Like:

```
The cat jumped over the moon very quickly.
```

The delimiter would be the space and the resulting strings would be:

```
The cat jumped over
the moon very quickly.
```

I see there is a `count` where I can see how many spaces are in there (Don't see how to return their indexes though).  I could then find the middle one by dividing by two, but then how to say split on this delimiter at this index.  Find is close but it returns the first index (or right first index using rfind) not all the indexes where " "  is found.   I might be over thinking this.

Comment: What about using `split()` and the re-joining the first and second half of the resulting list separately?

Comment: The algorithm you define (counting the spaces) would split the sentence into equal number of words, which conflicts with your requirement (split a string in the middle to the closest delimiter). Which one are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
s = "The cat jumped over the moon very quickly"

l = s.split()

s1 = ' '.join(l[:len(l)//2])
s2 = ' '.join(l[len(l)//2 :])

print(s1)
print(s2)
```

Comment: This method will collapse consecutive spaces into a single space. `"First␣sentence.␣␣And␣then␣the␣second."` will split the string into `"First␣sentence.␣And"` and `"then␣the␣second."`. Notice the collapsed [double space after the first sentence](http://widespacer.blogspot.com/2014/03/one-or-two-spaces-after-period-how.html). Tabs `\t` and newlines `\n` will also be converted to a single space when `join`ed. Using `s.split(" ")` will split on every individual space, which would maintain consecutive spaces when `join`ed, but you then have a problem when halving the split string.

Comment: This also breaks down for "sentence with looooooooooooooooooong word and many very short ones"

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
def split_text(text):
    middle = len(text)//2
    under = text.rfind(" ", 0, middle)
    over = text.find(" ", middle)
    if over > under and under != -1:
        return (text[:,middle - under], text[middle - under,:])
    else:
        if over is -1:
              raise ValueError("No separator found in text '{}'".format(text))
        return (text[:,middle + over], text[middle + over,:])
```

it does not use a for loop, but probably using a for loop would have better performance.

I handle the case where the separator  is not found in the whole string by raising an error, but change `raise ValueError()` for whatever way you want to handle that case.

Comment: You mean `under = text.rfind(" ", 0, middle)`.

Comment: Algorithmically speaking, this is as efficient as it can get.

Comment: @spaniard Although, I think you have to handle the case where find and rfind will return -1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `min` to find the closest space to the middle and then slice the string.

```
s = "The cat jumped over the moon very quickly."

mid = min((i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == ' '), key=lambda i: abs(i - len(s) // 2))

fst, snd = s[:mid], s[mid+1:]

print(fst)
print(snd)
```

#### Output

```
The cat jumped over
the moon very quickly.
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but that `min` call consumes a generator (i.e., a loop)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just split then rejoin:

```
text = "The cat jumped over the moon very quickly"
words = text.split()
first_half = " ".join(words[:len(words)//2])
```

Comment: Depends on whether you want to split by # of words or overall string length.

Comment: This split in equal amount of words, not characters

Answer (score 2):

I think the solutions using split are good. I tried to solve it without `split` and here's what I came up with.

```
sOdd = "The cat jumped over the moon very quickly."
sEven = "The cat jumped over the moon very quickly now."

def split_on_delim_mid(s, delim=" "):
  delim_indexes = [
      x[0] for x in enumerate(s) if x[1]==delim
  ] # [3, 7, 14, 19, 23, 28, 33]

  # Select the correct number from delim_indexes
  middle = len(delim_indexes)/2
  if middle % 2 == 0:
    middle_index = middle
  else:
    middle_index = (middle-.5)

  # Return the separated sentances
  sep = delim_indexes[int(middle_index)]
  return s[:sep], s[sep:]

split_on_delim_mid(sOdd) # ('The cat jumped over', ' the moon very quickly.')
split_on_delim_mid(sEven) # ('The cat jumped over the', ' moon very quickly now.')
```

The idea here is to:

- Find the indexes of the deliminator.
- Find the median of that list of indexes
- Split on that.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions with `split()` and `join()` are fine if you want to get half the words, not half the string (counting the characters and not the words). I think the latter is impossibile without a `for` loop or a list comprehension (or an expensive workaround such a recursion to find the indexes of the spaces maybe).

But if you are fine with a list comprehension, you could do:

```
phrase = "The cat jumped over the moon very quickly."

#indexes of separator, here the ' '
sep_idxs = [i for i, j in enumerate(phrase) if j == ' ']

#getting the separator index closer to half the length of the string
sep = min(sep_idxs, key=lambda x:abs(x-(len(phrase) // 2)))

first_half = phrase[:sep]
last_half = phrase[sep+1:]

print([first_half, last_half])
```

Here first I look for the indexes of the separator with the list comprehension. Then I find the index of the closer separator to the half of the string using a custom key for the [min()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#min) built-in function. Then split.

The `print` statement prints `['The cat jumped over', 'the moon very quickly.']`

Answer (score 0):

As Valentino says, the answer depends on whether you want to split the number of characters as evenly as possible or the number of words as evenly as possible: `split()`-based methods will do the latter.

Here's a way to do the former without looping or list comprehension. `delim` can be any single character. This method just wouldn't work if you want a longer delimiter, since in that case it needn't be wholly in the first half or wholly in the second half.

```
def middlesplit(s,delim=" "):
    if delim not in s:
        return (s,)
    midpoint=(len(s)+1)//2
    left=s[:midpoint].rfind(delim)
    right=s[:midpoint-1:-1].rfind(delim)    
    if right>left:
        return (s[:-right-1],s[-right:])
    else:
        return (s[:left],s[left+1:])
```

The reason for using `rfind()` rather than `find()` is so that you can choose the larger result, making sure you avoid the `-1` if only one side of your string contains `delim`.